# How to call your enum using a for or while method in java.?

Tags: java, arrays, enums

So i am trying to use a for or while method, to print out all of the objects in the main method.(Anna, Courtney, Ashley)

```
         public class JavaApplication56 {

        public enum details {

    Anna(" blue ", " blue"),
    Courtney(" red", " black"),
    Ashley(" yellow ", " green");

    String hairColor;
    String eyeColor;

    details(String hairColor, String eyeColor) {

        this.hairColor = hairColor;
        this.eyeColor = eyeColor;
    }

    public String getHair() {
        return hairColor;

    }

    public String getEye() {


        return eyeColor;
    }
}
```

I am getting an error under my main method that says bad operand type for binary operator.
First type int, second type details[].

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JavaApplication56 ja = new JavaApplication56();

    for (int person = 0; person < details.values(); person++) {

        System.out.println(details.values()+details.);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You will want to learn and follow Java naming conventions. All classes and enum names should begin with an upper-case letter. The Enum constants themselves should be all-cap.

Comment: Also, enums are constants (you already know the data when you prepare the program). The data you attempt to store appears to be variable (you don't know the exact data - it could be different each time). In such case, you should use other things like Lists, HashMaps etc. In this case, colours themselves could be an enum since there's a fixed number of colours hair and eye could be, and you know them already. But each person's name, hair colour and eye colour could be stored in a HashMap with the name as key and the colour enums as value.

Answer (score 1):

Or more simply:

```
// details should be re-named Details
for (Details detail : Details.values()) {
  System.out.println(detail); // does it have a toString() override?
}
```

Comment: _"does it have a toString() override?"_ In this case, it would be helpful to have the override but **not** mandatory. Since without override it's just `Object.toString()`, overriding it in the enum will allow cool things like `{return "Hair:"+hairColor+",Eye:"+eyeColor;}` :)

Answer (score 0):

Just like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    JavaApplication56 ja = new JavaApplication56();

    for (int person = 0; person < details.values().length; person++)
    {
        System.out.println(details.values()[person].name());
    }

}
```